# Remove selective hyphenations / punctuations based on list of exceptions

Tags: python, pandas

Remove selective hyphenations

```
import pandas as pd 
s = pd.Series(['do not-remove this-hyphen but remove-all of these-hyphens'])

list_to_keep =['not-remove', 'this-hyphen']
```

I want to keep the word hyphenations in the 'list to keep' but replace all other ‘-‘ in the series with a space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
S = s.str.split(expand=True).T[0]
' '.join(np.where(S.isin(list_to_keep), S, S.str.replace('-', '')))
```

Output:

```
'do not-remove this-hyphen but removeall of thesehyphens'
```

How it works.

- Create a pd.Series, S, using the string access and split then transpose
  dataframe and get the first column
- Use np.where to get only those terms that aren't in the list and use
  replace to remove the hyphen otherwise return the original term.
- Use join to reconstruct the string from the terms in updated pd.Series, S.

Answer (score 0):

A simple naïve solution would be:

```
s = 'do not-remove this-hyphen but remove-all of these-hyphens'    
words_to_keep = {'not-remove', 'this-hyphen'}

new_s = []
for word in s.split():
    if word not in words_to_keep:
        word = word.replace('-', ' ')
    new_s.append(word)

print(' '.join(new_s))  # do not-remove this-hyphen but remove all of these hyphens
```

Another approach with map:

```
def unhyphen_word(word):
    return word.replace('-', ' ') if word not in words_to_keep else word

print(' '.join(map(unhyphen_word, s.split())))
```

or list comprehension:

```
print(' '.join([unhyphen_word(word) for word in s.split()]))
```

Comment: It works with strings, but needs some changes to make it work for a column of a Pandas dataframe.  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really good with panda! Hope you forgive me :)

Answer (score 0):

**edit** hmm... it works but something seems wrong...

I'm not a master with regex but one way would be to do this in 2 steps:

1. Add `-` to the words to keep
2. Remove `-` from all that match pattern

Proof of concept:

```
import pandas as pd 
s = pd.Series(['do not-remove this-hyphen but remove-all of these-hyphens'])

words_to_keep = {'not-remove', 'this-hyphen'}

p1 = '|'.join(['(?!({}))-(?=({})[.,; ])'.format(*i.split('-')) 
               for i in words_to_keep])

p2 = '(?!\w+)-(?=\w+)'

s.str.replace(p1,'--').str.replace(p2,'')[0]
```

Returns:

```
'do not-remove this-hyphen but removeall of thesehyphens'
```

Comment: It works if one does not need space where we remove the hyphen.  It concatenates the words.  Thanks.